# strange existential type

Tags: haskell, existential-type

http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~jv/mpc08.pdf - in this article I cannot understand the following declaration:

```
instance TreeLike CTree where
...
abs :: CTree a -> Tree a
improve :: (forall m. TreeLike m => m a) -> Tree a
improve m = abs m
```

1. what difference (forall m. TreeLike m => m a) brings (I thought TreeLike m => m a would suffice here)
2. why does it permit abs here, if m in m a can be any TreeLike, not just CTree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a rank-2 type, not an existential type. What that type means is the argument for `improve` must be polymorphic. You can't pass a value of type `Ctree a` (for instance) to `improve`. It cannot be concrete in the type constructor at all. It explicitly must be polymorphic in the type constructor, with the constraint that the type constructor implement the `Treelike` class.

For your second question, this allows the implementation of `improve` to pick whichever type for `m` it wants to - it's the implementation's choice, and it's hidden from the caller by the type system. The implementation happens to pick `Ctree` for `m` in this case. That's totally fine. The trick is that the caller of `improve` doesn't get to use that information anywhere.

This has the practical result that the value cannot be constructed using details of a type - it has to use the functions in the `Treelike` class to construct it, instead. But the implementation gets to pick a specific type for it to work, allowing it to use details of the representation internally.

Comment: If the type system hides that the implementation uses CTree, do other TreeLike instances get cast or converted to CTree somehow?

Comment: oh, I got it. If we use leaf and node from TreeLike, we construct tree-like structure, but we don't specify which exactly implementation it is, so the compiler is free to choose the one that fits.

Comment: @SassaNF - Yes, mostly. Except the compiler doesn't choose by itself. It needs a hint from the implementation of `improve`. In this case, that hint is provided by using `abs` to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

Whether `m` can be "any TreeLike" depends on your perspective.

From the perspective of implementing `improve`, it's true--`m` can be any `TreeLike`, so it picks one that's convenient, and uses `abs`.

From the perspective of the argument `m`--which is to say, the perspective of whatever is applying `improve` to some argument, something that's rather the opposite holds: `m` in fact *must be able to be* any `TreeLike`, not a single one that we choose.

Compare this to the type of numeric literals--something like `(5 :: forall a. Num a => a)` means that it's any `Num` instance we want it to be, but if a function expects an argument of type `(forall a. Num a => a)` it wants something that can be any `Num` instance *it* chooses. So we could give it a polymorphic `5` but not, say, the `Integer` 5.

You can, in many ways, think of polymorphic types as meaning that the function takes a type as an extra argument, which tells it what specific type we want to use for each type variable. So to see the difference between `(forall m. TreeLike m => m a) -> Tree a` and `forall m. TreeLike m => m a -> Tree a` you can read them as something like `(M -> M a) -> Tree a` vs. `M -> M a -> Tree a`.

Comment: so how can the caller "create" a TreeLike that _can_ _be_ _any_ _TreeLike_ _we_ _choose_?

Comment: it was more of a `TreeLike m => m a` vs `(forall m. TreeLike m => m a)`. I think I got the distinction now. In the first case the caller can pass any "implementation" of TreeLike, and the implementation of the function can only use functions in TreeLike class, since that's all that's known about the argument.

Comment: In the second case the caller should pass only values, constructed "in a polymorphic way" using functions of TreeLike; the caller can't choose a particular "implementation"; that's actually a cool point - the caller declares he doesn't care what implementation is chosen. Then the choice of the implementation of `improve` forces the compiler to use functions from a particular instance to construct the value passed to `improve`.

Comment: @SassaNF: That's the basic idea, yeah. Again, think of `Num`--not only is `5` polymorphic, expressions using `(+)` and such are as well. So you can write a big arithmetic expression and pass it to a function that wants a polymorphic `Num` value, which could make it an `Integer` to get the value, or could use a `Num` instance for expression trees to see what operations you used, or both.

Comment: Yes, it is quite a revelation for a OOP-minded newbie. Once the value is constructed, it is conceptually not difficult to understand and quite familiar. It was the bit with the polymorphic way to construct the value that is tricky. In OOP speak, even the constructor becomes polymorphic (e.g. leaf in this article), and, in OOP-speak, now the caller writes the code against a abstract class, whereas the callee determines what concrete class the caller will use; which is kind-of inside-out, but extremely powerful.